# How to use longpress in appium?

Tags: appium, appium-android

I had tried lots of different `longpress` method but it do not work currently with appium.

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction();
action.longPress(webElement).release().perform();
```

above method do not provide duration to hold and press element.

Comment: You have added release with the long press. You need to remove release from the line and move the release button to the next line after a wait.

Comment: Hey Sandeep this code was written on appium forum page and wasn't working so i just shared below which is working fine.

Comment: consider up-voting my comment if it helped you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To press and hold (longpress) any element, i have mentioned code below which is working perfectly.

```
 WebElement holdElement= driver.findElementById("element");

  AndroidTouchAction t = new AndroidTouchAction(driver);   

  t.longPress(LongPressOptions.longPressOptions()
  .withElement(ElementOption.element(holdElement))
  .withDuration(Duration.ofMillis(5000)))
  .release()
  .perform();
```

here we can provide duration to press and hold element.